# Delete part of string with special characters with regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, expression

I am trying in python 3.7 to try to eliminate with Regex the sentence that begins with the character $. However, in doing so I also want to add the last comma of this amount.

My text is as follows:

> Sr,(a). INMOB OSIK DE EXAM SPA,$5.910,CASTILLA N. 111 BL. B DPTO.
> 111,FECHA VENCIMIENTO

**I need it to be as follows:**

> Sr,(a). INMOB OSIK DE EXAM SPA,CASTILLA N. 111 BL. B DPTO. 111,FECHA
> VENCIMIENTO

I have used this statement in python with library `re` but I cannot include the last comma of the value.

```
pattern = r'([$.])\w+'
regex_response = re.sub(pattern, '',str(regex_response))
```

but the result of this sentence is:

> Sr,(a). INMOB OSIK DE EXAM SPA,,CASTILLA N. 111 BL. B DPTO. 111,FECHA
> VENCIMIENTO

Any idea what the regex should look like to have that result?

Comment: Easiest: `([$.])\w+,?`, but `\$\d+(?:\.\d+)*,` [looks](https://regex101.com/r/9CkNrk/1) more correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously your code just works, all that is left is add the ',' character to the Pattern

```
pattern = r'([$.])\w+,?'
```

The above **',?** matches zero or one occurence of the ',' character